# Count SKU and return rows where QTY < Full QTY?

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm attempting to return rows where the "SKU_ID" is greater than 1 when counted in a sub query.

The issue i'm facing is when i run the sub-query independently it returns rows as expected. However, when i use in as part of a where clause i get the below error:

> ORA-01722: invalid number
>   01722.
>
> *Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
>
> *Action:   Specify a valid number.00000 -  "invalid number"

I've attempted the below...

```
SELECT inventory.sku_id, inventory.location_id, inventory.qty_on_hand, inventory.tag_id, inventory.full_pallet, sku_config.ratio_1_to_2 as "FULL QTY"
FROM inventory
                JOIN sku_sku_config ON inventory.sku_id = sku_sku_config.sku_id
                JOIN sku_config ON sku_sku_config.config_id = sku_config.config_id
WHERE inventory.sku_id in 
    (SELECT count(*)
                     FROM inventory
                     JOIN sku_sku_config ON inventory.sku_id = sku_sku_config.sku_id
                     JOIN sku_config ON sku_sku_config.config_id = sku_config.config_id
                     WHERE zone_1 NOT LIKE 'PROD' AND lock_status = 'UnLocked' AND full_pallet = 'N'
                     GROUP BY inventory.sku_id
                     HAVING count(*) >= 1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to compare `sku_id`s to `sku_id`s, not to counts.  So:

```
WHERE inventory.sku_id in 
    (SELECT i2.sku_id
     FROM inventory i2 JOIN
          sku_sku_config ssc
          ON i2.sku_id = ssc.sku_id JOIN
          sku_config sc
          ON ssc.config_id = sc.config_id
     WHERE zone_1 NOT LIKE 'PROD' AND
           lock_status = 'UnLocked' AND
           full_pallet = 'N'
     GROUP BY i2.sku_id
     HAVING count(*) > 1
    )
```

Note that I changed the comparison to `> 1` rather than `>= 1` based on the description of the problem.

Comment: Thanks Gordon! I was pretty close seeming as the issue was count(*) under the select statement. Everything worked.